# El archivo multimedia que estoy cargando de Drive con API no carga

Tags: javascript, php, api, google-drive

Estoy cargando varios archivos multimedia a mi reproductor desde una unidad compartida de Google drive. Esto mediante una cuenta de servicio, comprobé que conectara lo hace sin problemas, muestra todo perfecto. De hecho mediante la url : https://miweb.plesk.page/index.php?id=1WrdH_0hBHBmm5VPY3rCcPZZ2hqGgd123 Le paso ID y me devuelve el nombre del archivo y el tipo de formato pero en el reproductor no me muestra nada. En la consola no me muestra errores, estará relacionado con CORS o algo similar? agradezco sus ayudas.

Se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function getClient() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Drive Video Player');
    $client->setScopes([
        Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE, // Cambiar a DRIVE
        Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY
    ]);
    $client->setAuthConfig('cuentas.json');
    $client->setAccessType('online');

    return $client;
}



function get_drive_video_url($file_id, $client, $drive_id = null) {
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $queryParams = [
        'fields' => 'id, name, mimeType, webContentLink',
        'supportsAllDrives' => true
    ];

    if ($drive_id !== null) {
        $queryParams['driveId'] = $drive_id;
    }

    $file = $service->files->get($file_id, $queryParams);
    return $file;
}

$client = getClient();

try {
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $file_id = $_GET['id'];
        $drive_id = isset($_GET['drive_id']) ? $_GET['drive_id'] : null;
        $file = get_drive_video_url($file_id, $client, $drive_id);
        $access_token = $client->getAccessToken()['access_token'];

        if (!$access_token) {
            throw new Exception("Error: no se pudo obtener el token de acceso.");
        }

        $google_drive_link = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" . $file_id . "?alt=media&access_token=" . $access_token;
        $direct_link = "https://play.amazing-kirch.443-194-20-30223212.plesk.page/proxy.php?url=" . urlencode($google_drive_link) . "&access_token=" . urlencode($access_token);

        if ($file) {
            $file_name = $file->getName();
            $file_mime_type = $file->getMimeType();
        } else {
            $file_name = "Archivo no encontrado.";
            $file_mime_type = "";
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Se requiere un 'id' válido en la URL.");
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Manejar la excepción
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php echo $file_name; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.6.12/plyr.css" />
    <style>
        body, html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #videoPlayer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php if (in_array($file_mime_type, ["video/mp4", "video/webm", "video/ogg", "video/x-matroska"])) { ?>
        <video id="videoPlayer" class="plyr" controls>
           
        <source src="<?php echo $direct_link; ?>" type="<?php echo $file_mime_type; ?>">

            Tu navegador no soporta el elemento de video.
        </video>

        <script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.6.12/plyr.polyfilled.js"></script>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                const player = new Plyr('#videoPlayer');
            });
        </script>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <h1>No se puede reproducir este tipo de archivo.</h1>
    <?php } ?>
    <p>Nombre del archivo: <?php echo $file_name; ?></p>
    <p>Tipo MIME: <?php echo $file_mime_type; ?></p>

    <?php 
    echo "Token de acceso: " . $access_token;
    echo '<br><br><br><br><br><br>'; 
    var_dump($direct_link); 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi Archivo proxy.php:

```
<?php
function fetchRemoteResource() {
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36');
}

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400");

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

try {
    if (!isset($_GET['url'])) {
        throw new Exception('Error: URL parameter is required.');
    }

    $url = $_GET['url'];
    error_log('URL: ' . $url);
    error_log('Access Token: ' . $_GET['access_token']);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: Bearer ' . $_GET['access_token']]); // Agregar el token de acceso

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($response === false) {
        throw new Exception('Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ($httpCode >= 400) {
        throw new Exception('Error: HTTP ' . $httpCode . ' response from server.' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . 'Response:' . PHP_EOL . $response);
    }

    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $headers = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
    $body = substr($response, $header_size);

    $headerArray = explode("\r\n", $headers);
    foreach ($headerArray as $header) {
        $colonPos = strpos($header, ':');
        if ($colonPos !== false) {
            $headerName = substr($header, 0, $colonPos);
            if (trim(strtolower($headerName)) !== 'content-encoding') {
                header($header);
            }
        }
    }
    error_log('Headers: ' . print_r($headerArray, true));

    echo $body;
    curl_close($ch);

    error_log('Access Token: ' . $_GET['access_token']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: Bearer ' . $_GET['access_token']]);

    fetchRemoteResource();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Manejar la excepción
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Al ingresar al link contenido en la variable $direct_admin me dice:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has revisado el log de errores? En tu código se echa de menos precisamente un correcto manejo de errores, usando `try ... catch` por ejemplo. Y es que pueden ocurrir cosas como que el archivo exceda el máximo permitido que es de `5120GB`
 [según la doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert).

Comment: Gracias por responder A. Cedano. Actualicé el post con el error 403 que me manda al ingresar a la ruta generada por la variable $direct_link y agregué también el archivo proxy.php. Me parece curioso ese error 403 porque el servidor rechaza la conexión como si no tuviera permisos, pero si fuera el caso no mostraría ni el nombre ni el tipo de archivo y los tokens (Estoy usando credenciales de la cuenta de servicio) se actualizan cada vez que caducan

Comment: Pues los errores 403 son relativos a los permisos. ¿Esa cuenta de servicio tiene permisos para crear archivos en Drive? O, ¿en tu código, al conectar, estás pasando un *scope* con permisos suficientes para crear archivos? Por lo que veo aquí: `$client->setScopes([Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY]);` parece que le pasas permisos sólo lectura. [Revisa aquí](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive.html) el alcance de cada Scope y elige uno que te permita crear archivos.

Comment: Intenta pasarle el scope `DRIVE_FILE` (no queda claro ahí si ese scope permite crear archivos: `$client->setScopes([Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY]);` y si no funciona, le pasas el scope `DRIVE` sin más: `$client->setScopes([Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY]);`

Comment: Bueno sí, con `DRIVE_FILE` debería ser suficiente, cuando vayas a trabajar con algún método de la API revisa siempre la documentación, en el apartado [**Autorización**](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create?hl=es-419#auth) te dice qué permisos te permiten usar el método (`create` en este caso).

Comment: Una aclaración: todo lo dicho anteriormente es si tuvieras problemas en cuanto al archivo (por ejemplo, el mismo no se crea correctamente). Eso no queda claro en la pregunta. Conviene que revises directamente en Drive si el archivo se crea correctamente.

Comment: Actualicé el archivo index.php con algunas mejoras, sin embargo sigo sin tener éxito. Los errores, solo ese de permisos le pasé el scope pero sigue igual... ¿Algo más podrías sugerirme para intentar? Te agradezco mucho

Comment: Estuve viendo acerca de esto: Delegación de todo el dominio
Si otorgas a esta cuenta de servicio acceso a los datos de tu organización mediante la delegación de todo el dominio, debes hacerlo con precaución. Para revertir esta acción, puedes inhabilitar o borrar la cuenta de servicio o quitar el acceso mediante la Consola del administrador de Google Workspace. Se debe otorgar permisos aquí o no es necesario?

Comment: Debes verificar dos cosas: 1. Que la API de Google Drive está habilitada para el proyecto de Google Cloud Platform en el que has creado la cuenta de servicio, puedes verificarlo en la sección `APIs y Servicios Habilitados`; 2. En la cuenta de servicio haz clic en el símbolo del lápiz (editar) y luego ve a permisos y da el permiso al menos de `Editor` a esa cuenta, colocando el valor de la dirección email de la misma que es algo como: `elNombreDeTuCuentaDeServicio@QueIncluyeUnNumeroParecidoA-1804547305832.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: Ya lo tengo hecho, A. Cedano es más ahora que lo mencionaste lo revisé nuevamente para verificar que así fuese

Comment: Revisa y ya dirás. De.todos modos no me queda claro si revisaste que el archivo se crea en Drive o si el problema es tratando de ver el archivo una vez creado.